# How can I create a scope function the return json in Angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a function like this:

```
 $scope.GetDays = function() {
         $http.post("core/ajax/LoadDays.php").success(function(data){
                 return data[0].days;
    }); 

};
```

And in LoadDays.php I have this json:

```
 [{"days":"1"}]
```

If I do console log It will return correct: 1. But, the problema is When I call it on my HTML code. I recive a looping erros : $rootScope:infdig

How can I do this?

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on the concept of Ajax (asynchronous javascript), because that's what you're doing here.

You should do something like this:

```
$scope.GetDays = function() {
         $http.post("core/ajax/LoadDays.php").success(function(data){
                 $scope.days= data[0].days;
    }); 

};
```

And then use `{{days}}` in your html. Days will be filled with data shortly after you call `GetDays()`, depending on how fast the server request is handled.

Comment: If you define that function in your controller and that controller is defined in the html, you can simply call it with `{{getDays()}}` within the scope of that controller. If that doesn't work, you misconfigured something, but it's impossible to find out what, from the code that you posted.

Comment: Yes, when I do that {{getDays()}} I get the error $rootScope:infdig, I will try to find out whats is going on. Thank you.

Comment: @MinearenaMine you don't need curly braces to call scope function, just `ng-click="getDays()"`